# How to change the limits for geo_shape in altair (python vega-lite)

Tags: python-3.x, geojson, vega-lite, altair

I am trying to plot locations in three states in the US in python with Altair. I saw the tutorial about the us map but I am wondering if there is anyway to zoom the image to the only three states of interest, i.e. NY,NJ and CT.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
from vega_datasets import data            
states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'states')

# US states background
background = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white',
    limit=1000
).properties(
    title='US State Capitols',
    width=700,
    height=400
).project("albers")
            
points=alt.Chart(accts).mark_point().encode(
        longitude = "longitude",
        latitude = "latitude",
        color = "Group")

background+points
```

I inspected the us_10m.url data set and seems like there is no field which specifies the individual states. So I am hoping if I could just somehow change the xlim and ylim for the background to [-80,-70] and [35,45] for example. I want to zoom in to the regions where there are data points(blue dots).

Could someone kindly show me how to do that? Thanks!!

[image]

#### Update

There is a field called ID in the JSON file and I manually found out that NJ is 34, NY is 36 and CT is 9. Is there a way to filter on these IDs? That will get the job done!

Answer (score 3):

Alright seems like the selection/zoom/xlim/ylim feature for geotype is not supported yet:
[Document and add warning that geo-position doesn't support selection yet #3305](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3305)

So I end up with a hackish way to solve this problem by first filtering based on the IDs using pure python. Basically, load the JSON file into a dictionary and then change the value field before converting the dictionary to topojson format. Below is an example for 5 states,PA,NJ,NY,CT,RI and MA.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
# Load the data, which is loaded as a dict object
us_10m  = data.us_10m()
# Select the geometries under states under objects, filter on id (9,25,34,36,42,44)
us_10m['objects']['states']['geometries']=[item for item in us_10m['objects'] \
      ['states']['geometries'] if item['id'] in [9,25,34,36,42,44]]
# Make the topojson data
states = alt.Data(
    values=us_10m, 
    format=alt.TopoDataFormat(feature='states',type='topojson'))

# Plot background (now only has 5 states) 
background = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white',
    limit=1000
).properties(
    title='US State Capitols',
    width=700,
    height=400
).project("mercator")

# Plot the points
points=alt.Chart(accts).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    longitude = "longitude",
    latitude = "latitude",
    color = "Group").project("mercator")

# Overlay the two plots
background+points
```

The resulting plot looks ok:

[image]